# ModelBinding with Steve Sandersons BeginCollectionItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I'm using Steve Sandersons `BeginCollectionItem` extension to help with binding lists of items. This works fine for primitive types. The problem I'm having is that for a custom model binder that I've written I can't see how to generate the full name and index of the item that I'm binding to.

Currently my model binder looks like this:

```
public class MoneyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder 
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Amount");

        if (valueResult != null)
        {
            var value = valueResult.AttemptedValue;
            var currencyCode = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Iso3LetterCode").AttemptedValue;

            var money = (Money) bindingContext.Model;

            Money parsedValue;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                money.Amount = null;
                return;
            }

            var currency = Currency.FromIso3LetterCode(currencyCode);

            if (!Money.TryParse(value, currency, out parsedValue))
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", string.Format("Unable to parse {0} as money", value));
            }
            else
            {
                money.Amount = parsedValue.Amount;
                money.Currency = parsedValue.Currency;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel Lokks like this (some propertis omitted for clarity):

```
public class EditFeeEarningCapacityViewModel
{

    public List<FeeEarner> FeeEarners { get; set; }

    public class FeeEarner
    {
        public Money AverageChargeOutRate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Edit Template for the Money type looks like this:

```
@model Core.Money
@{
    int decimalPlaces;
    if(!int.TryParse(string.Format("{0}", ViewData["DecimalPlaces"]), out decimalPlaces))
    {
        decimalPlaces = 0;
    }
}
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">@Model.Currency.Symbol</span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount,
                                                                new
                                                                {
                                                                    placeholder = string.Format("{0}", Model.Currency),
                                                                    @class = "input-mini",
                                                                    Value = String.Format("{0:n" + decimalPlaces + "}", Model.Amount)
                                                                })
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Iso3LetterCode)
```

For a form that has post values like this:

```
FeeEarners.index    3fa91d09-0617-4bea-ae3f-d84862be8c04

FeeEarners[3fa91d09-0617-4bea-ae3f-d84862be8c04].feeEarner.AverageChargeOutRate.Amount  500
FeeEarners[3fa91d09-0617-4bea-ae3f-d84862be8c04].feeEarner.AverageChargeOutRate.Iso3LetterCode  GBP
```

I can't see how to detect the index of the item or the property name that I'm binding to. So essentially, how do I find the index of the item I'm trying to bind to and the name of the property that I'm trying to bind the data from?

Comment: @steven-sanderson You should get Steve to look at this as he is a member :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not fimilar with that Helper but for collection i am doing a bit different trick.

define key

```
var key = "EditModel[{0}].{1}";
```

var index = 0;

then build form

```
foreach(var fee in Model.FeeEarners){
   @Html.TextBox(string.Format(key, index, "PropertyNameFromYourFeeClass"));
//It will build text box and set value
}
```

On Controller side
create action with input parameter

```
public ActionResult Save(EditFeeEarningCapacityViewModel editModel){
...your code here
}
```